# Cut-off frequency in coaxial cable

Tags: transmission-line, inductance, low-pass, coax

The cut-off frequency of an RL circuit is described by the following equation: 
$$f = \frac{R}{2\pi L}$$ where R is the [resistance](http://www.chemandy.com/calculators/round-wire-resistance-calculator.htm) of the circuit and L is the [inductance](https://www.eeweb.com/tools/coax-inductance). Applying this equation to a straight length of [RG-58/U](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RG-58) coax cable (no resistors or inductors in the circuit) with the following specs: $$Length = 5m$$
$$OD = 5mm$$
$$ID = 0.81mm$$
$$L = 0.00000159H$$
$$R = 0.163\Omega$$
yields a cut-off frequency of [16.32KHz](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Low-pass-filter-calculator.php#answer2). I know the cable is good for at least a few GHz. What's going on here? Does the formula not work for distributed inductances?

Comment: That formula does not work for distributed inductances, no.  And I'm suspicious of your resistance measurement -- it seems too high.

Comment: That might apply to short circuit current BW but if you use matched R source and load, the RLC Telegrapher's equation prevails for distributed RLC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That formula does not apply to distributed inductances.

Coax cable *does* have a cutoff frequency, when wavelength of the signal gets somewhere on the order of the diameter of the cable (it's some fraction, like 1/4, but I can't remember exactly).  For most coax, that cutoff frequency is considerably higher than the useful frequency of the cable because of dielectric dissipation -- it is educational to find specifications for various sorts of coax and look at their attenuation/meter at various frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftKVvU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you short circuit the source and load impedance **then** you get what you calculated with 2pif=R/L